# Eclipse not showing Russian characters

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, utf-8

I imported project. When I opened it, saw this:
[image]

I tried to solve this problem myself: Opened Preferences->General->Content types->then updated default encoding to **utf-8** but without success
[image]

Then I tried this: Preferences->General->Workspace->Text File Encoding->Other: UTF-8 but this is also without success.
[image]

After that I tried to open Run->Run configurations->Common->Encoding->Other:UTF-8
[image]
Unfortunately this is also without success. It is still not showing Russian characters, not in code editor, not in console. So my question, how to show Russian characters in Eclipse?

Comment: Maybe problem is not only in Eclipse, but if files too? Maybe unicode BOM is required? Sometimes i had "service" to polish files with simple editor Scite to guarantee having BOM. Othodox say not code in such charsets, use \1234

Comment: Are You sure this is not one of "one byte" encoding like 1250 / 1252 etc?

Comment: @JacekCz, can I do that process using SublimeText?

Comment: sorry, I don't know what is it

Comment: Are you using a font which can display Cyrillic? 'Menlo' should work on a Mac.

Comment: Your first solution solved my problem. Russian characters were not showing correctly in eclipse console. I was trying to system.out.println some russian characters and eclipse showed '?' characters instead. Preferences->General->Content types->then updated default encoding to utf-8 changed '?' characters to correct Russian characters. Thank you.